# Calculation in 1 line VBS

Tags: vbscript, calculator

How can I make this Calculator work if the user enters 1+1?
It only works if I enter 1 + 1 ;C
The calculation must be in 1 line.

```
x = inputbox("Calculation", "Calculator", "1+1")
y = Split(x)
if not isnumeric (y(0)) then 
wscript.quit 
end if 
if not isnumeric (y(2)) then 
wscript.quit 
end if 
if y(1) = "+" then
z = int(y(0)) + int(y(2))
msgbox(z)
end if
if y(1) = "-" then
z = int(y(0)) - int(y(2))
msgbox(z)
end if
if y(1) = "*" then
z = int(y(0)) * int(y(2))
msgbox(z)
end if
if y(1) = "/" then
z = int(y(0)) / int(y(2))
msgbox(z)
end if
if y(1) = "%" then
z = int(y(0)) MOD int(y(2))
msgbox(z)
end if
```

Thanks for any Answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try next code snippet (commented for explanation):

```
Dim ii, sOperator, strExpr, y 
strExpr = inputbox("Calculation", "Calculator", "1+1")

' insert spaces around all operators
For Each sOperator in Array("+","-","*","/","%")
  strExpr = Trim( Replace( strExpr, sOperator, Space(1) & sOperator & Space(1)))
Next
' replace all multi spaces with a single space 
Do While Instr( strExpr, Space(2))
  strExpr = Trim( Replace( strExpr, Space(2), Space(1)))
Loop

y = Split(strExpr)
''' your script continues here
```

**Another approach** (allows more than pure *arithmetic* operations) using [`Eval` Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094(v=vs.84).aspx) (which *evaluates an expression and returns the result*) and basic [error handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h(v=vs.84).aspx):

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0

Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName
Dim strExpr, strInExp, strLastY, yyy
strInExp = "1+1"
strLastY = ""
Do While True

  strExpr = inputbox("Last calculation:" & vbCR & strLastY, "Calculator", strInExp)

  If Len( strExpr) = 0 Then Exit Do 

  ''' in my locale, decimal separator is a comma but VBScript arithmetics premises a dot  
  strExpr = Replace( strExpr, ",", ".")   ''' locale specific

  On Error Resume Next             ' enable error handling
  yyy = Eval( strExpr)
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    strInExp = CStr( yyy)
    strLastY = strExpr & vbTab & strInExp
    strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & strLastY
  Else
    strLastY = strExpr & vbTab & "!!! 0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description
    strInExp = strExpr
    strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & strLastY
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0                  ' disable error handling
Loop

Wscript.Echo strResult
Wscript.Quit
```

**Sample output**:

```
==> cscript //NOLOGO D:\VB_scripts\SO\39934370.vbs
39934370.vbs
1+1     2
2/4     0,5
0.5**8  !!! 0x3EA Syntax error
0.5*8   4
4=4     True
True+5  4
4=5     False
False+5 5
5       5

==>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a much simpler way if having multiple files doesnt matter where you log it to a .txt file and use "set /a" in batch to simple calculate it.

In the vbs file:

```
calculation = inputbox("What do you want to calculate?(include =)", "Eclips-Terminal Calculator")
oFile.write "" & calculation & ""
oFile.close
wsh.run "calculator.bat"
wscript.sleep 3000
msgbox rfile.readall
oFile.close
```

In the batch file(calculator.bat):

```
@echo off
set /p math=<RAM.txt
set /a calculation=%math%
echo. >> RAM.txt
echo %calculation% >> RAM.txt
```

And then a text file called "RAM.txt".
Its my nice, clean and simple way wich isnt too hard to pull of.

EDIT: I know this is a 4 year old question i just couldnt find a simple fix so i added it here so others can find it.